# Typedef inside a C struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

First off the code which boggles my mind:

```
typedef struct Object {
    typedef int MyInt;
    void (*destructor)(Object *);
    void *(*constructor)(struct Object *);
} Object;
```

Why does the compiler prevent me from defining a typedef inside a struct?

Comment: because C is not C++.

Comment: Well I found something similar in Windows kernel data structures I believe it is in C 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @user2533527, it's not the same. That typedef is on global scope (like the first one on mic4ael's post), and that is legal and fairly common. We're discussing typedefs _inside_ a struct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C language every declaration inside `struct` must declare a data field (possibly unnamed). That means that it is possible to define types inside a `struct` in C, as long as the new type declaration is embedded as a part of a data field declaration. For example

```
struct Outer {
  struct Inner {
    int i;
  } field;
};

struct Outer a;
a.field.i = 42;
```

In the above example type `struct Inner` is declared inside type `struct Outer`. However, the "nested" `struct Inner` type declaration is not in any way localized inside `struct Outer`. It will still have file scope, since C language has no such thing as `struct` scope. This means that you can still use `struct Inner` as a member of the same file scope

```
struct Inner b;
b.i = 42;
```

Meanwhile, this trick is not applicable to `typedef` declarations, since `typedef` declarations do not declare data fields.

Note that in the spirit of C language, even if your `typedef` declaration was somehow legal, it would still declare a typedef name `MojInt` with file scope. I.e. it would behave exactly the same as if you placed your `typedef` declaration before the `struct`.

Answer (score 8):

It's just not allowed. Something similar is allowed in *C++* classes, but not in standard C.

Comment: Mind the difference between a C struct and a C++ class. It's more substantial than some people seem to think.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't know it was allowed in C++, but I can tell for certain that I have seen no vanilla C compiler accept that construct.

Here is a browsable C99 grammar that may hopefully clear up confusions: http://slps.github.io/zoo/c/iso-9899-tc3.html

Check the 1998 C++ grammar for comparison: http://slps.github.io/zoo/cpp/iso-14882-1998.html