# How to determine the size of pointed-to data without dereferencing?

Tags: c, typedef, c99

### In Short

In standard C, how can the size of pointed-to data be determined from a pointer but without dereferencing it?

### In More Detail

I wish to implement C99 immitations of the containers in the standard C++98 library, as shown below:

```c
#define vector(ElemType)            \
    struct {                        \
        ElemType *data;             \
        size_t count;               \
        size_t capacity;            \
        // typedef ElemType eltype; \ // not permitted in C!
    }

/* ... */

vector(double) dv;

vector_create(&dv, 10);
vector_pushback(&dv, 35.4);
vector_destroy(&dv);
```

The major problem is that C does not permit `typedef`'s inside a `struct`, see in [separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20336244/4827735).

I am currently using an extra data member of `size_t` to keep track of `sizeof (ElemType)`. Is there a way to get the `sizeof (ElemType)` from the `data` pointer without dereferencing it?

Comment: What type is the first parameter to `vector_create` etc? `void *`?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen The `vector_create` and others are macros too.

Comment: Note that you cannot use `//` comments inside a multiline macro: the \ will just paste the following line into the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the size of the type, you can apply `sizeof` to the data itself:

```
sizeof(*dv.data)
```

Or simply:

```
sizeof *dv.data
```

But I find the parenthesized version more readable.

The pointer `dv.data` can be `NULL`, it is not dereferenced, for this simple example, `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time.

> **C11 6.5.3.4**
>
> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

As a matter of fact, it is the recommended way to pass the object size to `malloc`:

```
ElemType *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * capacity);
```

Using `sizeof(*p)` instead of `sizeof(ElemType)` prevents size mismatches that could go undetected if you later change the type of `p`.

There is no way to get the number of elements of the array `dv.data` points to, without maintaining the count separately, which is the purpose of the `capacity` member.

Comment: How come the `dv.data` is not dereferenced by the `*` operator? Can you please point me to your sources?

Comment: @Log:  I updated the answer with a quote from the Standard. sizeof is a property of the type of its operand.  The operand is not evaluated, except for very rare pathological cases, for C99 specific constructs such as `sizeof(char[rand()])`.  In your case, `dv.data` is a pointer to `ElemType` which is `double`, not a VLA.

Answer (score 1):

In C99 one can use `sizeof(*dv.data)`.

Comment: Not just C99, `sizeof(*dv.data)` is available in C89 and even earlier dialects of C.